# Disable typing in the AutoCompleteBox

Tags: jquery, telerik, mvp

**Scenario:**

I have made a messaging page in which I have used telerik `AutoCompleteBox` for the name to whom I have to send the message. Their is a button beside the `AutoCompleteBox` on which when user clicks, a list appears and he can select the names from that. I have not bind the `AutoCompleteBox` with any source. So when user enters any thing in the box an pop up message saying source "The Control `Datasource` or `DatasourceId` is not set."

**Question**

I dont want user to type any thing in the `AutoCompleteBox` and select the user from the list. So any one please help me with the solution how to disable user to enter any thing in the Box.

**Note:**

We can't disable the AutoCompleteBox because then it won't return the entered value in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            disableKeyPress("AutoCompleteBoxID");

        });

        function disableKeyPress(control) {
            $jQuery("[id$=" + control + "]").on('keydown', function (e) {
                var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
                if (key != 9) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
```

**"9"** is for tab. This will accept only tab